How for each cell in a row return and concatenate multiple matches without dragging down formulas?
I have a list of items and in another place I have list that covers some of these items each time with a different key.
How to fill in column B all matching results next to the original item (column A) from column E without dragging the formula down manually?




A
B
C
D
E




1
Item
Matching keys

Item
Key


2
foo
apple,testing

foo
apple


3
anything


bar
orange


4
bar
orange,something

foo
testing


5
another thing


bar
something



If dragging down then B2 and below will be:
=join(",", iferror(filter(E:E, D:D=A2), ""))
=join(",", iferror(filter(E:E, D:D=A3), ""))
=join(",", iferror(filter(E:E, D:D=A4), ""))
=join(",", iferror(filter(E:E, D:D=A5), ""))

Ideally B2 would have been:
=arrayformula(join(",", iferror(filter(E:E, D:D=A2:A), ""))

But both array join and filtering by a more than 1 value (D:D=A2:A) aren't supported by Google Sheets.
Queries also don't seem to support it: =arrayformula(join(",", query(D:F, "select Col2 where Col1='" & A2:A & "'"))) acts as if it's just & A2 &.
It's a bit similar to How to concatenate all further columns from duplicated items of a first column? (which utilized a LET function), except this time it should be applied inside the original list and not as as standalone summary.

Use map(), tocol() and filter(), like this:
=map(tocol(A2:A, 1), lambda(item, 
  ifna(join(", ", filter(E2:E, item = D2:D))) 
))

See
map(),
tocol()
and
filter().

Interesting. Is it better/faster than the arrayformula/byrow version? Also, why writing it as filter(E2:E, item = D2:D) instead of filter(E2:E, D2:D = item) when either works and the latter might look more understandable?

You're right about arrayformula(), I've removed it. But those optimization tips don't claim that iferror is an anti-pattern. Does your usage of ifna not expand all the way the bottom too?

Alright, I've removed the value. Now it's down to byrow VS the combination of map and tocol.

The results are identical indeed, I just wonder which is quicker with large datasets.

Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.

Just making a note - if column E was filled with numbers here's how to use something similar to return the largest closest value to what's in column A - =MAP(A2:A, LAMBDA(item, INDEX(D2:D, MATCH(MIN(FILTER(E2:E, E2:E >= item)), E2:E, 0)))) - it's also a nice way to actually pulling off Index/Match for multiple rows.

Finally I've managed to do it via Filter assisted by BYROW/LAMBDA, hope it'll help others to put this in B2:
=IFERROR(BYROW(filter(A2:A, A2:A<>""), LAMBDA(a, JOIN(",", FILTER(E:E, F:F = a)))))
The IFERROR is needed to avoid writing #N/A in cells that have no matches.
